# Typescript on React HOC

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, eslint

I have a React HOC structured like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { CookiesConsumer } from './index';

const withCookies = (WrappedComponent: any) => (props: any) => (
  <CookiesConsumer>
    {cookies => (
      <WrappedComponent
        {...props}
        cookiesContext={cookies}
      />
    )}
  </CookiesConsumer>
);

export default withCookies;
```

I get 2 Typescript eslint warnings on this that I'd like to fix. Both on the `any` type declarations:

`Unexpected any. Specify a different type.eslint(@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any)`

For the `props` type, I don't know what properties or value types might be in the props object, so how can I define it better than `any`?

For the `WrappedComponent` type I've tried types like `ReactNode` or `ReactElement` but that throws a new error on the actual usage of : `JSX element type 'WrappedComponent' does not have any construct or call signatures.`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
import React from 'react';
import { CookiesConsumer } from './index';

interface withCookiesProps {
    someProp: boolean;
  }


const withCookies = <P extends object>(WrappedComponent: React.ComponentType<P>) => (props: P & withCookiesProps) => (
  <CookiesConsumer>
    {cookies => (
      <WrappedComponent
        {...props}
        cookiesContext={cookies}
      />
    )}
  </CookiesConsumer>
);

export default withCookies;
```

[Refernence](https://medium.com/@jrwebdev/react-higher-order-component-patterns-in-typescript-42278f7590fb)

Comment: Feel like I'm 95% there with this but struggling a little because the example you give is a bit different. Would you be able to provide an example where the props are unknown like my component?

Comment: Let me know if it's ok, if no I will check it out again.

Comment: OK I think we're there! My example doesn't have any props for withCookies so I removed that from your example but the rest seems to get rid of existing errors.